# tabBar VS. tabView

Tags: android, android-tabs

When working with android Styles.xml, what is the difference between:

```
<style name="customTabBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
<style name="customTabBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabBar">
```

Answer (score 2):

`TabBar` is for the whole bar, `TabView` is for one tab.

If you want to customise TabViews and use it in your theme, do for example:

```
<style name="MyTabViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <!-- define your custom properties here -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_background</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">32dp</item>
</style> 

<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTabViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: how do i style one tabview then